# Nginx gzip not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, gzip, http-compression

As the title said, Nginx Gzip is not working, I have tried many configurations scattered on the internet none have worked, I'm really frustrated when simple things don't work.

`gzip.conf:`

```
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    application/json
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    text/xml
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    text/javascript
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    font/opentype
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon;
```

`Chrome:`

[image]

[image]

`Chrome Audit:`
[image]

`Curl:`
[image]

I have cleared the cache and everything still the same.

=======================

**UPDATE:**

I have tested for gzip compression at

http://checkgzipcompression.com/

and gave me:

[image]

but in `Chrome` it shows:

[image]

Comment: Anyone can help on this issue? i have tried everything.

Comment: added more screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit was my anti-virus, I thought it was not because at first, I have disabled it and the response are still not `gzipped`. But when i tried in a newly installed VM with the same chrome version in my workspace, the response got `gzipped`, and when I installed the anti-virus on that VM, the response was not `gzipped` again.

Answer (score 2):

Since gzip works fine on your server with other HTTP clients (`curl`,  `http://checkgzipcompression.com`) but not in `Chrome`, I would suspect Chrome to be the culprit, not your nginx configuration.

1. Try other browsers (`Firefox`, `IE`, `Opera` etc.)?
2. Try disabling all Chrome extensions (anything related to User-Agent, since you have `gzip_disable "msie6"` in your nginx conf)